# Bulk upload into Odoo (OpenERP)

Tags: javascript, upload, macros, odoo

I am having a small issue using Odoo,

I have more then 1000 file to upload into Odoo V11 (*.pdf/*.stp), each file in attached to a P/N, I managed to have the adresse link for every par number created in odoo, but still i dont know how to make a bulk upload,
Now i am trying to create a macro for upload file per file but i am stuck in the first part.
I never used JavaScript before :/

here is the the main page of the PN :11050-1-A
[image: main page]

when i lunch chrome console to click automatically in "ajouter" (Add) with

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('input_file_XXXX');
el[0].click();
```

i got a files dialogbox
[image: Files dialog]

lets say that the file is stored in desktop and called "11050-1-A - Test.pdf"

How can I automatically select the file?
Do you have another idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have let's say more than 100 of these that needs to be imported once, you will need to create a Python script that uses Odoo's XML-RPC to upload the files. The process will be:

- Connect to the XML-RPC and authenticate
- Search for a product with the name
- Search for the file on your computer
- Create a new `ir.attachment` that links to the product

XML-RPC link: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html